# Using Selenium to find an HTML element with classes inside a href

Tags: java, jquery, html, selenium

I have an element in my page as follows. How can I use Selenium to get the text, "Add New Member".

```
<a ng-if="userCanEdit" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope" ui-sref="orgs-add" href="#/orgs/add">
     <i>Add New Member</i>
</a>
```

I did try this code below, but it does not work

```
System.out.println( driver.findElement( By.cssSelector( "a[href='#/orgs/add']" ) ).getText() );
```

Also, my javascript console, evaluates the expression, `('a[href="#/orgs/add"]')` correctly.

EDIT : I just got a crash as follows, when I try the above code.

```
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=a[href='#/orgs/add']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:465)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at hello.validate(hello.java:101)
    at hello.main(hello.java:60)
```

Comment: so what output are you getting from the code you have mentioned?

Comment: Your HTML says "#/members/add", but your cssSelector uses "#/orgs/add". Any chance you made a typo - and you simply need to use "#/members/add"?

Comment: @StoyanBerov, no that's not the cause. I just edited above. I was trying to post a sample.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj, I have edited above with the result I get

Comment: This is just to let you know I made a quick test in C# with static HTML and successfully scraped your code:

using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/");                
                var result = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a[href='#/orgs/add']")).Text;
            }

This leads me to believe the problem could be due to Angular somehow. Maybe try to scrape with IsJavaScriptEnabled and some delay for the page to load. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When using Selenium with Angular, in most of cases, you may need to add some explicit wait since the DOM element is dynamically created / modified by Angular.

For example, you can try to add explicit wait using below code:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Replace `By.id("myDynamicElement")` with your element locator.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement( By.cssSelector( "a.btn.btn-primary.ng-scope" ) ).getText();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
driver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-primary ng-scope")).getText();
```

Comment: This won't work because you can't use compound classnames.